# AsyncTask.get() not waiting after moving to new class with startActivity()

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have one class called trailsActivity that extends Activity. I create a new instance of my AsyncTask called mapPreLoad, and I execute it in trailsActivity.

Then I use `startActivity()` to move to my new class trailInformation that also extends Activity. From trailInformation a button is pressed to move to a new class mapPopup that extends MapActivity. In mapPopup I end onCreate by calling "`trailsActivity.mapPreLoad.get();`" but the `.get()` call does not wait for the task to be completed, and I am getting errors as a result.

Is there any way that I can make this work, or should I consider redesigning my process entirely? If you need any more details please ask.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TrailsActivity.java**

Start with AsyncTask.

On Asyntask onPostExecute method

```
Intent intent=new Intent(this,TrailInformation.java);
intent.putExtra("result","Whatever result you got");
startActivity(intent);
```

**TrailInformation.java**

onButton Click Do Following.

```
    Intent intent=new Intent(TrailInformation.this,mapPopup.class);
    intent.putStringExtra("result",getIntent().getStringExtra("result"));
    startActivity(intent);
```